# how to approach legibility problem of light text in dark GTK theme

Tags: themes, gtk, gtk3, accessibility

I'm working on a dark GTK theme for Ubuntu. This largely is going well, but I am not sure how to deal with certain scenarios such as instances of programs with a light colour scheme. A representative example is the Ubuntu Software Centre. You can see below that the light coloured text is difficult to read against the light background of Ubuntu Software Centre:

[image]

Given that a dark theme (i.e., general dark colours in the theme with light text) is necessary for my purposes, what would be some reasonable way to approach this legibility problem?

Comment: Does http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1913590 help?